# How to get cowplot minor grid lines to be the standard ggplot default soft grey, not solid black

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar(fill = "#56B4E9", alpha = 0.8) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.05))) +
  theme_minimal_hgrid()
p1
```

[image: cowplot default]

Cowplot v1.0.0 seems to work fine. See above. Things break though when I try to add minor gridlines to the plot above:

```
p1 + theme(panel.grid.minor.y = element_line())
```

[image: plot with minor gridlines]

Why does it plot the gridlines as solid black instead of a soft grey? I know I could probably specify `color = "lightgrey"` but I'm not sure if lightgrey is the proper grey to match everything else, and would prefer to use defaults. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57500433/4975218) is correct. However, note that cowplot provides a function `background_grid()` specifically to make this easier. You can simply specify which major and minor lines you want via the `major` and `minor` arguments. However, the default minor lines are thinner than the major lines, so you'd have to also set `size.minor = 0.5` to get them to look the same.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
#> 
#> ********************************************************
#> Note: As of version 1.0.0, cowplot does not change the
#>   default ggplot2 theme anymore. To recover the previous
#>   behavior, execute:
#>   theme_set(theme_cowplot())
#> ********************************************************
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar(fill = "#56B4E9", alpha = 0.8) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.05))) +
  theme_minimal_hgrid() +
  background_grid(major = "y", minor = "y", size.minor = 0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the theme you are using has explicitly set the `panel.grid.minor` element as `element_blank()`. When you then set `panel.grid.minor.y` it inherits its parameters from the blank element rather than the theme’s `panel.grid` element. `element_blank()` doesn't have a colour, so the default black is used instead.

If you set `panel.grid.minor` to `NULL`, both x and y minor grids will then inherit their parameters from `panel.grid`:

```r
p1 + theme(panel.grid.minor = NULL)
```

[image]

Note that if you were using a continuous x axis you'd also have to set `panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()` to avoid vertical gridlines in this case.

Created on 2019-08-14 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).